# Docker: Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Tags: node.js, docker, sass

I am using Docker with live reloading for local development with a React frontend, a Node.js backend, and an Nginx server, on Windows 10. I can get these three services started and detecting changes but the client fails to compile every time no matter what I do. Here's the error code:

```
Failed to compile.
client_1  | ./src/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/main.scss)
client_1  | Error: Missing binding /client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux_musl-x64-64/binding.node
client_1  | Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 10.x
client_1  |
client_1  | Found bindings for the following environments:
client_1  |   - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
client_1  |
client_1  | This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
client_1  | Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

I am first installing the packages locally and then creating the containers and building the images with docker-compose.

**client/Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /client

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml** (with the other services stripped off for brevity)

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: myapp-client
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./client:/
      - ./client:/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
```

I have tried these Node.js images to no avail:

```
node:10
node:latest
node:lts
node:10.16.3
node:8.1.0-alpine
```

I have read about using `RUN npm rebuild node-sass` in my Dockerfile after `RUN npm install` but that would only work in production because for local development I am installing my packages from a script in `package.json`

Comment: Are you copying your *host* node modules into the *container*? The error message seems clear: the Windows version of Node-sass is installed, but the Linux version is needed. Copy in the package file then install *inside* the container.

Comment: I am very new to Docker so I might be wrong but I don't think I'm copying anything. In production I would have things like ```COPY package*.json /client/ RUN npm install COPY . /client/``` on the Dockerfile, but not here. I know I could add those instructions and Docker would install node-sass on a Linux environment with (probably) the right binaries. But that way I would have to reinstall every package every time I restart the containers instead of running an install script once when I clone the project from GitHub and running another one to go into development mode faster.

Comment: You won't have to, because the layer is cached. So, if `package.json` is not modified, you won't install it on every build.

Comment: You're not using the COPY command, no, you're mounting the local directories into the container. But it's the same problem - you're loading Windows deps in a Linux container. If you don't want them in the image you can mount a *different* host directory at the `node_modules` path and install the Linux deps into that.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same scenario today. I am using sass in my React client and that needs `node-sass`. The next step was to dockerize the client that's when I stumbled on this issue. My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml is very much similar to the one provided in the Question except for the `volumes` inside `docker-compose.yml` which looks like below -

```
- ./client:/app
- /app/node_modules
```

My WORKDIR inside Dockerfile is `/app`